# Cannot switch between speaker and headphones

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, speakers, headphones

My laptop has just been acting up and I am not sure what caused it. It used to be a normal laptop for the longest time but lately it is showing some weird signs:

- When laptop restarts, if headphones are connected then it would not go back to playing with speaker.
- Same is true if it starts playing with speakers, it would not go back to headphones

I have read some SuperUSer threads and all the other links online and tried following things already

- Setting headphones as my default playback device - Does not work
- Uninstalling and installing the RealTek sound driver software again - Does not work

Also, some people suggested that there is a bug in Windows 10 BUT this is not even windows 10 this is purely windows 7 and I am not sure what the problem is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried going to Realtek Audio Manager -> Device advanced settings and toggling "Mute the rear output device, when a front headphone is plugged in" or "Make front and rear output devices playback two different audio streams simultaneously"?

Comment: @spherical_dog: The only option I see there is Classic Mode/Multi Stream mode....